# The remote server returned an error: (416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

Code which i tried :

```
string contents = string.Empty;

using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{    
   contents = wc.DownloadString("http://www.bizjournals.com/albany/blog/health-care/2015/10/what-this-local-bank-did-to-control-health-care.html");    
}
```

but its throwing error

> The remote server returned an error: (416) Requested Range Not
>   Satisfiable

Answer (score 2):

It appears that some webservers may return a 416 if your client does not send a User-Agent header. Try adding the header like this:

```
wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705");
```